# Add a product subtitle in Woocommerce archives pages

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I can add a subtitle to my product title by adding the following code to single-product/title.php:

```
the_title( '<h1 class="product_title entry-title">', '</h1>' );
echo "<p>My subtile</p>";
```

The problem is that this only appears on the product page. Not on other views such as the shop view:

[image]

I have looked everywhere and cannot find out where to modify the title for other views of the WooCommerce store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated** - To add a product subtitle in archives pages like shop use the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_subtitle', 20 );
function woocommerce_shop_loop_item_subtitle() {
    global $product;

    echo '<p>' . __("My subtile", "woocommerce") . '</p>';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.